# changing MVP without violating OPEN-CLOSED principle

Tags: android, kotlin, interface, architecture, mvp

I have created this Program using MVP
and a Model class with dummy data without an interface as the method parameter

**Model**

```
override fun getAllItem(): List<Item> {
    val obj = JSONObject(data)
    val itemsArray = obj.getJSONArray("items").toString()
    val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

    return gson.fromJson(
        itemsArray, object : TypeToken<List<Item>>() {}.type
    )

}
```

**Contract**

```
interface Model {

   
    fun getAllItem(): List<Item>
}
```

but while using volley getAllItem method needs an interface, since there is a delay before data is received, and it also can fail.

**Model**

```
override fun getAllItem(result: Contract.Model.ReceivedDataItems) {
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
    val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, baseUrl,
        {
            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
            val itemsList = gson.fromJson<List<Item>>(it,
                object : TypeToken<List<Item>>() {}.type
            )
            result.onSuccessItems(itemsList)
        },
        {
            result.onFailed()
        })
    
    queue.add(stringRequest)
}
```

**Contract**

```
interface Model {
   
    fun getAllItem(result: ReceivedDataItems)
    
    interface ReceivedDataItems {

        fun onSuccessItems(items: List<Item>)
        fun onFailed()
    }

}
```

I know the first Model is not standard, but this code is not predictable and making a new Model will break the OPEN-CLOSED principle.

how to avoid or predict this?